# Add "contenteditable" attribute to element using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm drawing a div with Javascript and adding various attributes to it as I build it. I can get ids, classes and style attributes working but it just ignores "contenteditable".

```
var elemText = document.createElement('div');
elemText.className = 'elem';
elemText.style.background = "none";
elemText.id = "elementID";
elemText.contenteditable = "true";
```

I've also tried

```
elemText.attributes['contenteditable'] = "true";
```

Still no joy.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The property is [`contentEditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.contentEditable) (note the capital 'E'). Attributes are set using [`setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.setAttribute) rather than the [`attributes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.attributes) collection. So, either of the following will work:

```
elemText.contentEditable = "true";
elemText.setAttribute("contenteditable", "true");
```

Comment: Yes, the property name is `contentEditable`.

Comment: Why the capital E? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable

Comment: @putvande because the JavaScript naming scheme uses camel-back capitalization.

Comment: @putvande: Because the docs say so: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.contentEditable also http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#contenteditable

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.setAttribute)?

```
elemText.setAttribute('contenteditable', true);
```